# problem with creating a new window with custom tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

When I run the below code cutsom tkinter for some reason , doesn't allow the new (top level) window to be on the top

```
from customtkinter import CTk, CTkToplevel, CTkLabel, CTkButton

class Gui:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = CTk()
        self.root.geometry('600x600')
        self.new_window_button = CTkButton(master=self.root, text="Open new window", 
                                           width=120, height=36, command=self.new_window)
        self.new_window_button.pack()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def new_window(self):
        new_window = CTkToplevel(self.root)
        CTkLabel(master=new_window, text="This is a new CustomTk window").pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Gui()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CTk is kinda weird and I might know a solution!

I added `new_window.grab_set()` in the `new_window` so the code knows to keep the new window on top of the main one!

The fixed code will be:

```
from customtkinter import CTk, CTkToplevel, CTkLabel, CTkButton

class Gui:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = CTk()
        self.root.geometry('600x600')
        self.new_window_button = CTkButton(master=self.root, text="Open new window", 
                                           width=120, height=36, command=self.new_window)
        self.new_window_button.pack()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def new_window(self):
        new_window = CTkToplevel(self.root)
        new_window.grab_set()  # Set focus to the new window
        CTkLabel(master=new_window, text="This is a new CustomTk window").pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Gui()
```